# PostgreSQL connection failure with SonarQube 8.5

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, continuous-integration, sonarqube, md5

I've installed SonarQube 8.5 over a CentOS 7 system and it started before I set up a PostgreSQL 9.6 connection (with embedded database, then).
So I moved on:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=####
...
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
```

This is what I've got in my /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

Since I added the database (named "sonar") connection, it failed with no helpful logs. Only those:

> 2020.11.06 13:47:16 WARN  es[][o.e.d.c.s.Settings] [http.enabled] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.

> 2020.11.06 13:47:25 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143

> 2020.11.06 13:47:24 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[*client*][[timer]]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:\n java.base@11.0.8/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)\n app//org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$CachedTimeThread.run(ThreadPool.java:574)

So I tried to fix and test the database account here:

```
ALTER USER sonar WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '####';
ALTER ROLE
...
psql -d "postgresql://sonar:####@localhost/sonar" -c "select now()"
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "sonar"
```

NB: I've been trying it with AND without encryption, as ROOT user and POSTGRES user... but no luck.

Comment: "*Ident authentication failed for user "sonar"*" - you need to fix your [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't understand what's wrong with it. Plus it was taken from a previous server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry but does it have to be located elsewhere??

Comment: Well, the pg_hba.conf that is used is apparently not the one you included in your question otherwise you wouldn't get that error. If you can connect as the superuser using `psql`, then you can use `show hba_file;` to find the file that is being used

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks a lot : the expected filepath should be /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf according to this useful command!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments above for configuration fix. In the first place, the default PG version from yum in Centos OS 7 wasn't even right.